# How do I find the source of Android/Gradle "out of memory" errors?

Tags: android, react-native, detox

I'm trying to get a React Native app to build, using Detox for e2e testing, and am getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError (no error message)`. The app builds fine if Detox is out of the equation. I'm on a macbook pro w/ 16GB RAM.

- multiDex is enabled
- javaMaxHeapSize is 16g in my app build.gradle
- I have `JVM_ARGS="-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"` in my shell

I'm new to Android, and the only documentation I can find about memory leaks assumes you're able to build the app and profile it.

Comment: could you share how you are building the app?

Comment: I'm trying to build the app via detox-cli, using `detox build -c android.emu.release`